# Why reading existing sqlite database generate a new file

Tags: php, sqlite, codeigniter

I am trying to read a existing sqlite database file in codeigniter using PDO connection. My question is actually two fold:

1. Reading the existing sqlite database actually creates a new db file along with the original one. assume the original db filename is `a.db`, the new one will be `a.db;dbname=`.
2. Subsequent db statements operate on the `a.db;dbname=`. I have tried to run create table, insert new value on this new db file. both run fine. However, select statement returns nothing and no error either.

I am baffled at this point.. Please help.

updated with the related settings:

```
// sql

$this->db->query('create table x (y int)');
$this->db->query('insert into x values(6)');
$result = $this->db->get('x')->result();  // $result is an empty array

// config/database.php

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'sqlite:/home/perlwle/db/a.db';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

/home/perlwle/db/a.db is the sqlite database file and owned and writable by www-data.

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you show the code where you make the DB connection?

Comment: Your are telling the computer that the file name is `a.db;dbname=`. Show that code.

Comment: updated with the code. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/726) in CodeIgniter; you have to update.